# Odd failures with PS v2 remoting

Tags: powershell

I have a moderatly complex script made up of a PS1 file that does `Import-Module` on a number of PSM1 files, and includes a small amount of global variables that define state.

I have it working as a regular script, and I am now trying to implement it for Remoting, and running into some very odd issues. I am seeing a ton of .NET runtime errors with eventID of 0, and the script seems to work intermittently, with time between attempts seeming to affect results. I know that isn't a very good description of the problem, but I haven't had a chance to test more deeply, and I am just wondering if I am perhaps pushing PowerShell v2 further than it can really handle, trying to do remoting with a complex and large script like this? Or does this look more like something I have wrong in code and once I get that sorted I will get consistent script processing? I am relatively new to PowerShell and completely new to remoting.

The event data is

> .NET Runtime version : 2.0.50727.5485 - Application ErrorApplication
>   has generated an exception that could not be handled. Process ID=0x52c
>   (1324), Thread ID=0x760 (1888). Click OK to terminate the application.
>   Click CANCEL to debug the application.

Which doesn't exactly provide anything meaningful. Also, rather oddly, if I clear the event log, it seems like I have a better chance of not having an issue. Once there are errors in the event log the chance of the script failing is much higher. 
Any thoughts before I dig into troubleshooting are much appreciated. And suggestions on best practices when troubleshooting Remote scripts also much appreciated.

Comment: One thing about v2 remoting is that the shell memory limit is set pretty small - 150 MB.  You might try bumping that up to say 1gb like so - `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 1024 -force`

Comment: Keith, that did the trick. Once I set it it 2GB! I'll have to do some research to see if there are implications to setting it that high. Luckily most machines I will be dealing with will have at least 8GB of RAM, and lots of them have 32.

Comment: Not sure if I should add this here or start a new thread. But perhaps related, so I'll start here.
Now that I am not crashing I have a new issue. The script looks for a network path, and only when running remote I am getting failures in my log saying the network path isn't found. This is a UNC path, which I was thinking would work when remoting, but perhaps I have a new problem? Or perhaps there is another nifty setting? I am running the script that initiates Remoting as a user with admin rights on the target machine, and when I log in as that user on the target machine the path is valid.

Comment: FWIW, I am using Invoke-Command -asJob, which as I understand it means the script is actually running on the target machine. Not sure if that makes a difference. What my Google-Fu has found suggests that UNC paths are the way to go, but I am concerned I may still have a double hopping issue.

Comment: Hrm, found a couple of references to all the config needed to allow second hoping. Pretty sure that's my issue, so please disregard the questions above. hopefully by morning I can have this not only working, but have a way to enable it for multiple machines easily.

Comment: Yup, second hop is likely the issue.  Use -Auth CredSSP. FYI I converted my first comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

One thing about v2 remoting is that the shell memory limit is set pretty small - 150 MB. You might try bumping that up to say 1gb like so:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 1024 -force
```